# ThreeJs: Why am i having distortions around the edges of my 3D object.

Tags: three.js

This is the configurator i have [made so far with ThreeJs](https://ngcouture.herokuapp.com/) , it is a 3D shirt configurator, but my biggest problem is the fact that it has distortions around the edges, which make it so unclear and low poly, please what is the cause of this, is it because i am using JSON meshes. I tried this on PlayCanvas and it came out perfectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're referring to the stepping or jagged artifacts around the edges of model, that's called "aliasing". You can reduce it by enabling anti aliasing in the `THREE.WebGLRenderer`.

Change

```
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
```

to

```
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true });
```

to fix it.

Hope that helps!